# can't import import static org.assertj.android.api.Assertions.assertThat;

Tags: android, fest

I am trying to create a test project

I have downloaded the source for AssertJ
from [here](https://github.com/square/assertj-android)

And their instruction says I need to do

```
import static org.assertj.android.api.Assertions.assertThat;
```

but that is not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use `gradle` to build your project?

Comment: Then it's harder to help you. `Google` switched from `Ant` to `Gradle` and now there is no separate test project.

Comment: I figured our how to add FEST, however it seems i can only test activities and views. Do you know how I can test Model or Controller objects? that do not inherit from activity/fragment/view classes ?

Comment: import static org.fest.assertions.api.ANDROID.assertThat;
import static org.fest.assertions.api.Assertions.assertThat;